# Pass total value from observable variable in ngx-paypal

Tags: angular, paypal, rxjs

I am using `ngx-paypal` to introduce a paypal pay button in a page. I have the cart object represented like this:

```
  cart$: Observable<Cart>;
```

as a local variable. What is the recommended way to to pass the total from `cart$` (`.total`) to the standard config from `ngx-paypal`:

```
private initConfig(): void {
    this.payPalConfig = {
      currency: 'EUR',
      clientId: 'AXVj0j1Qk2K6OD2ai7TezGja3QxzK-lAFlTrVT5EiWHL-uFbu3Ce2d2Tg9Jo-13YpiJIzGgNIRkz9lKs',
      createOrderOnClient: (data) => <ICreateOrderRequest> {
        intent: 'CAPTURE',
        purchase_units: [
          {
            amount: {
              currency_code: 'EUR',
              value: this.cart$.totalPriceWithTax.value,
              breakdown: {
                item_total: {
                  currency_code: 'EUR',
                  value: '9.99'
                }
              }
            },
            items: [
              {
                name: 'Enterprise Subscription',
                quantity: '1',
                category: 'DIGITAL_GOODS',
                unit_amount: {
                  currency_code: 'EUR'
```

Is it ok if I subscribe to `cart$` in `initConfig` and initialize `this.payPalConfig` inside the subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have `cart$` as an observable and the value of `payPalConfig` depends on emissions from `cart$`, it would probably be simplest to define the config as an observable that derives from `cart$`, something like this:

```
  public paypalConfig$ = this.cart$.pipe(
    map(cart => this.buildPaypalConfig(cart.items))
  );
```

You would create a `buildPaypalConfig` method that builds up the config object, from the `cart$` emission.  Then, in the template, you can pass `paypalConfig$ | async` to the `ngx-paypal` component, like this:

```
<ngx-paypal [config]="paypalConfig$ | async"></ngx-paypal>
```

This ensures the `ngx-paypal` component always has a config that reflects the most up-to-date changes of the `cart$`.

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hvdlou?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) sample.